# <p> cannot show after fade out , what's wrong?

Tags: jquery

Why the #hello can fade out but not show anymore?? thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#hello').delay(1000).fadeOut();
  $('#hello').show();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What? Your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to wait until the fadeOut effect is done by providing a callback to it:

```
$(function() {
    $('#hello').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $('#hello').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.show()` is getting called before the `.fadeOut()` has started.

Try this:

```
$('#hello').delay(1000).fadeOut(function(){
    $('#hello').show();  
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/ZVD6z/

Answer (score 0):

In your example the `show()` function is being called before the `fadeOut` has finished. If you change it to:

`$('#hello').delay(1000).fadeOut(function() { $('#hello').show(); });`

Then the `hello` `p` element will appear again as soon as the fade out is complete.

Answer (score 0):

It can, the problem is that `.show()` is being called before `.fadeOut()` due to your delay.

To fix it, try:

```
$('#hello').delay(1000).fadeOut().show(); //Will reappear immediately
```

or

```
$('#hello').delay(1000).fadeOut().delay(1000).show(); //Will reappear after 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the fadeOut callback to specify the actions to do when the animation is over

```
$(function() {
    $('#hello').delay(1000).fadeOut(function() {
        $('#hello').show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BfjsX/